# Loading scripts on every page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domdocument, dom-manipulation

I have the issue of loading the same scripts across all my pages without having to define them all over and over.

I've came up with a half complete solution which looks like...

```
var scriptLocs = [];

function loadScripts() {
    for (var i = 0; i < scriptLocs.length; i++) {
        var crtElement = document.createElement('script');
        crtElement.src = scriptLocs[i];
        var hh = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        // Getting head tag
        hh.appendChild(crtElement);
        //Adding it to head
    }
}​
```

The array can be very big e.g. around 120 scripts (2.5MB) these include such things as jQuery and Knockout etc...

The problem im having is this can be unreliable my function seems to miss out, or load  in a different order than defined in my array. The order is very important as some things may rely on jQuery so it must be loaded before other scripts.

Also its differnt errors on every refresh ... E.g. maybe differnt loading order?

Is there away of define all the scripts in an element then appending the lot of them at once? would this work?

UPDATE:

Using this test.js file

```
for (var i = 0; i < scriptLocs.length; i++) {
    document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + scriptLocs[i] + "\"><\/script>");
}
```

And including it as the very first thing in the head like..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

Seems to solve this problem

Comment: This is what we are doing the now, but for example if we want to add a new script we have to go thorugh every single page and add it...

Comment: u could have only the jquery file load on every page and use the $.script function to retrieve the remaining scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `document.write()` is for.  Frequently it is misused, but in this case, it's a good choice:

```
var scriptLocs = [...];
for (var i = 0; i < scriptLocs.length; i++) {
    document.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\""+scriptLocs[i]+"\"><\/script>");
}
```

But do not put this in a function or call it from an event handler.  This script should run immediately while the page is loading.  Calling `document.write()` after the dom has loaded causes problems.

Comment: Update my code, it works is there anyway to make it better for large arrays? of large javascritps? Can i also do the same for including CSS

Comment: @Liam - Yes, you can write out `<link>` tags or any arbitrary HTML you want.  The HTML is written to the document immediately following the script tag that writes it. [Performance shouldn't be a problem...](http://jsfiddle.net/QyGsR/) If you are including so many script files that you are worried about the loop taking too long, you should be more worried about the time it will take for the browser to subsequently parse all those script files.

Answer (score 3):

with that many scripts you should maybe consider compressing and concatenating them and serve them as one minified script.

You could do this with [Googles closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/compressing-javascript) or [the YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#work) for example:

Comment: Also its differnt errors on every refresh ... E.g. maybe differnt loading order?

Comment: one more thing you'll get rid of when using concatenation ;)

Comment: Could you expalin more please?

Comment: Another library you could use is [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) . I haven't used it personally, but it seems like the best fit. The difference with all of these tools is that instead of manually maintaining the array of scripts, each script says what it needs and loads it.

Comment: it simply means `putting all your (minified) scripts in one large file` in this case. This will not only increase the performance, but ensuring script get loaded in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to declare dependencies and specify loading order which is something that [require js](http://requirejs.org/) handles quite well. Additionally,

> RequireJS has an optimization tool that ... [c]ombines
>   related scripts together into build layers and minifies them via
>   UglifyJS (the default) or Closure Compiler (an option when using
>   Java).

This would allow you to to have a single minified script to include across all pages in your application.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the sizes of the scripts you are calling ?
the array will follow you order and element creation will follow your order, but remember you are calling them in javascript, so it'd never wait for a script to load and then load the other one, i.e. if you are loading jquery which is 100 kb for example and you are calling some native script which is 10 kb, so your script will be loaded first this the jquery.
you add attribute async to make the dom don't wait for your scripts.

Comment: How do i go about doing that?

Comment: @LiamMcCann just add the attribute async if you are using document.write and if you are appending the new node you may use crtElement.setAttribute('async',true);